# No funciona Inicio de Sesion con PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html, sweetalert

Tengo creada una base de datos con MYSQL que tiene usuarios registrados con email y contraseñas (las contraseñas están encriptadas). No logro hacer que el inicio de sesión funcione. Se queda en blanco y no se vuelve a cargar la página.

Mi html es:

```
<main>
        <div class="h-screen md:flex">
            <div
                class="relative overflow-hidden md:flex w-1/2 bgPersonalizedImage from-blue-800 to-purple-700 i justify-around items-center hidden">


            </div>
            <div class="flex md:w-1/2 justify-center py-10 items-center bg-white">
                <form class="bg-white" method="post" action="validatecredentials.php">
                    <h1 class="text-gray-800 font-bold text-2xl mb-1">Hola de Nuevo!</h1>
                    <p class="text-sm font-normal text-gray-600 mb-7">Un gusto tenerte nuevamente</p>
                    <div class="flex items-center border-2 py-2 px-3 rounded-2xl mb-4">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                            fill="currentColor">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 9a3 3 0 100-6 3 3 0 000 6zm-7 9a7 7 0 1114 0H3z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                        <input class="pl-2 outline-none border-none" type="email" name="email" id="email"
                            placeholder="Email" />
                    </div>


                    <div class="flex items-center border-2 py-2 px-3 rounded-2xl">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                            fill="currentColor">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd"
                                d="M5 9V7a5 5 0 0110 0v2a2 2 0 012 2v5a2 2 0 01-2 2H5a2 2 0 01-2-2v-5a2 2 0 012-2zm8-2v2H7V7a3 3 0 016 0z"
                                clip-rule="evenodd" />
                        </svg>
                        <input class="pl-2 outline-none border-none" type="password" name="contra" id="contra"
                            placeholder="Contraseña" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit"
                        class="block w-full bg-green-600 mt-4 py-2 rounded-2xl text-white font-semibold mb-2">Iniciar
                    Sesión</input>
                    <span class="text-sm ml-2 hover:text-blue-500 cursor-pointer">Olvidaste tu contraseña</span>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Luego tengo mi PHP que establece conexion con la base de datos y se fija que el usuario haya estado registrado. Si se ha registrado con éxito, lo redirige a la página tienda.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$contra = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contra', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$hashedContra = hash("sha256", $contra);
$host = "******";
$username = "******";
$password = "*******";
$dbname = "******";

//Crear la conexion SQL
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Conexión fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT email, password FROM webcustomers WHERE email = ? AND password =?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $email, $hashedContra);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  echo "<script>swal({
      title: 'Sesión Iniciada con éxito',
      text: 'Contraseña y email correctos',
      icon: 'success',
      button: 'Siiii',
    });</script>";
    
  $hashedCookieEmail = hash("sha256", $email);
  $hashedCookiePass = hash("sha256", $contra);

  // Guarda la cookie encriptada
  setcookie("emailUsuario", $hashedCookieEmail, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
  setcookie("contraUsuario", $hashedCookiePass, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
  header('Location: https://strant.store/tienda.php');
exit();
   } else {
    echo "<script>swal({
          title: 'No se ha podido iniciar sesión',
          text: 'Contraseña o email incorrectos',
          icon: 'error',
          button: 'Ups',
        });</script>";
   }

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

El problema es que no redirige al usuario a la pagina tienda.php. Además, tampoco muestra las alertas de SweetAlert.

He intentado varias formas de solucionar esto, como haciendo otro archivo PHP que compruebe si están las cookies en el navegador y según si están o no, que muestre el formulario de iniciar sesión o un cartel que diga "Se ha iniciado sesión", pero no ha funcionado correctamente. Es por esto que prefiero intentar con el código actual y que se compruebe si están las cookies en el navegador, en caso de que sea así que se muestre un cartel que diga "Ya has iniciado sesión".

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te está dando un error y si no los tienes activados no te los muestra.

```php
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
?>
```

¿Sabes si llega a está línea?
¿Es correcta la URL del fichero tienda.php. No sería más lógico directorio_relativo/tienda.php?

```php
header('Location: https://strant.store/tienda.php');
```